# PyVis Assigning Colors to Edges or Nodes

Tags: python, pyvis

I have developed a network visualization using PyVis. The script works fine but now I need to show the edges and the nodes in different colors to help the users to differentiate. Can someone help to assign a different colors to both edges and nodes.

```
from pyvis.network import Network
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("C:\\aaaa\\Desktop\\devices.csv", sep=",", header=None)
data.columns = ["devices", "customer_number"]

sample = data
#sample.head(10)

net = Network(
    notebook=True,
    directed=True,
    cdn_resources="remote",
    height="1000px", width="100%", bgcolor="#222222", font_color="white", 
    #select_menu=True,
    filter_menu=True,
)

nodes = list(set([*sample.devices, *sample.customer_number]))
edges = sample.values.tolist()
net.add_nodes(nodes)
net.add_edges(edges)

net.repulsion(
    spring_length=100,
    damping=0.01,
)
net.show('mygraph.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

There does not appear to be any direct method in `pyvis` to set the edge color, although you can iterate through the edges in a network, and each will be a Python dictionary:

```
for edge in graph.get_edges():
   print(edge)
```

Then it's possible to set a color for a specific edge, for example:

```
edge["color"] = "red"
```

Similarly for a specific node:

```
node["color"] = "#d2d493"
```